# how to echo some unique character

Tags: string, echo

I want to echo some unique string to a file. Sample code like bellow:

```
{
echo "    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined"
echo "    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common"
} >> file.conf
```

When i run it, file.conf become seperate in to 2 file.
How i can echo it with a correct way?

Thank You

Comment: You have an unquoted double-quote and an unquoted `>` redirection in the string you're trying to echo, so the output goes to file `s`. Either escape the quotes within the quotes, or put the whole string in single-quotes (`'`) so you can include double-quotes (and backslashes) without quoting.

`echo '    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
echo '  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s> %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" combined"'
echo '  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b common"'
} >> file.conf
```

Since you are not doing any double quote interpolation, then it makes it easy to move your echo string inside of single quotes '...' to simplify quoting.